# Invalid operation, resultset is closed when executing another statement inside a resultset

Tags: java, sql, db2, database-connection, resultset

I am extracting a lot of data from a number of columns and upload them to FileNet. Once uploaded, I will update a column from the same table where the values are extracted.

***while loop***

```
while(rs.next) {
    //get column1
    //get column2
    //etc.

    try {
        upload(datafromcol1, datafromcol2, datafromcol3);
        updateFlagSuccess(key);
    } catch (EngineRuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

***setFlagSuccess method***

```
public void setFlagSuccess(int key) throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = null;
    Connection con = null;
    String querySuccess = "UPDATE FROST_DMS SET STATUS = 'S' WHERE DOC_KEY = '" + key + "'";
    try {
        con = getConnection();
        Loggers.general().trace(LOG, "Query: {}", querySuccess);
        statement = con.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(querySuccess);
        Loggers.general().trace(LOG, "Status flag updated");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        con.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I think when the line `"statement = con.createStatement()"` executes it creates another `ResultSet` thus closing the previous `ResultSet`. But the requirement is to update the status flag every successful upload. So I have to update a column every after a successful extraction.

Steps I tried:

1 - I tried adding `conn.setAutoCommit(false)` from the start, and manually commits the transaction after the `while` loop via `conn.commit();` This didn't work.

2 - I defined another connection. The connection variable for the previous `PreparedStatement` producing the `ResulSet` in the `while` loop is `conn`. Notice another connection defined in the method `setFlagSuccess`, which is `con`.

> Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? And if not, is there a workaround?

I am using DB2 V10.5

Comment: collect the results from your first query into a `Collection` and do the updates in a separate loop iterating this `Collection`.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I am uploading a document and extracting metadata from the database. I am getting 13 properties each loop for the document. This could take a lot of space during runtime considering that my code is run in EOD. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Did you **profile** your current implementation or do you just *guess* that you have a memory problem?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I just guessed. :D It's client's machine anyway. I'm looking at the collection approach right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aldryl

Looks like you could use scrolled `ResultSet`. More about it you can read in `Updating Rows in ResultSet Objects` part of [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) tutorial on the official oracle web site, which means that you can try to update your entries directly during your read.

Please let me know if it helps, otherwise I will delete the answer to not making a confusion.

Comment: exactly what I need! I included the column I am updating in the query and updates it in the same result set. Thank you!

Comment: @AldrylYakitMedrano happy that it helped. Good luck in your attempts.